# casting void* to std::function

Tags: c++11, casting, void-pointers, std-function

I have an issue. I'm trying to convert a void* to std::function.
This is just a simple example, any suggestions will be appreciated

```
#.h file
class Example {

public:

  Example();
  int foo(void* hi);

  int fooFunc(std::function<int(int, int)> const& arg, int x, int y) {
    foo(arg.target<void*>(), x, y);
    return 2;
  }

};


#.cpp file
Example::Example() {

  }

  int Example::foo(void * func, int x, int y)
  {
    //cast back to std::function
    func(x, y);
    std::cout << "running in foo: " << a << "\n";
    return a;
  }
```

Every casting i tried did not work.

I know i can send a `std::function` in this example, but it's for something bigger and i'm working on an example to make it work here.

The whole meaning of `void*`, is for sometimes to use it, in these situations, when you don't know what you will receive, and then cast it to the specific usage you need.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you do that? What is the `void*` coming from (some `dlsym`?). Notice that closures are bigger than one pointer.

Comment: Some dsystem lib. If i wouldn't have to. I would not have done it

Comment: It isn't possible to store a `void*` in a `std::function`, because it isn't callable. Your call to `target` will always return a null pointer.

Comment: I see..so no option to cast it both ways?

Comment: I would have to work with a pointer to std funtion?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it (don't comment it).

Comment: Why should i edit? It's good that people know it's not possible to do this cast.  Stop giving -1 on questions, that cannot be done. It's good to know that too.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

You can cast a data pointer to `void*` and then back to the same pointer type you have started with. `std::function` is not a pointer type, so the cast is statically invalid, and it's not the same thing you have started with. You have started with a `.target` of type `void(*)()` but it's not a data pointer, it's a function pointer, so casting it to `void*` and back is implementation-defined.

You can:

1. Ignore the issue and cast to `void(*)()` anyway. Will work on most (but not all) platforms.
2. Use `void(*)()` instead of `void*` as a universal function pointer (you can cast it to other function types).
3. Use whatever tools C++ offers to avoid the cast altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried it out already, C++ allows for the use of std::any ( #include any ) in lieu of the traditional void pointer, and it has a lot of the features we see in std::unique_ptr:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any

Hopefully this does what you need it to.